# how can i paretoken when i use jwt token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have values ​​in the url like this

```
          console.log("url:",url)
              url: demo://app?accessToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJwcm92aWRlciI6Imtha2FvIiwiaWF0IjoxNjE4MzIwOTg1fQ.Ver4V9lOBamkgU-DQC91LnVZLuvkLOGgytXPnkOWsFg
```

I want to parse the token in the url and put it in the maintoken.

how can i do that?

this is my code

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    Linking.addEventListener("url", ({url}) => {

    console.log("url:",url)


    const maintoken = parseToken(url);

    console.log("token:",token);
    })
    return () => Linking.removeEventListener("url");
    },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

if the `url` always start with `demo://app?accessToken=` you can just do a substring.

```
const mainToken = url.subString(22);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to implement. But, if you are trying to extract values from a JWT and adding them to another signed JWT on the frontend, then it's not possible.

Tampering or trying to change the values in a hashed JWT token makes it an invalid token.

The whole objective of using a JWT token is to ensure nobody can tamper with the token and/or the data contained in it. Once a JWT is signed by whichever JWT module you are using, its signed with the purpose of making sure the data cannot be changed.

Because if you could change the values in the JWT and the JWT still passes as a valid token, then that would compromise your entire authentication process.

Also, don't append JWTs to URLs. It's bad practice. If you have a logging system in place that records all API calls, then your tokens will be recorded in the logs, because URLs are usually saved in logs. Anyone with access to the logs can decode the token and use the payload in the token for malicious reasons. Use HTTP headers instead.

**What you should do**

- If you have to decode the URL on frontend and have no other option, use [jwt_decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) it will return the payload hashed in the JWT.
- Send those decoded values to your server.
- Sign a new access token on the server, use those values as payload in the access token.
- Send back the newly signed access token to the frontend for use.

If the URL token is something that was created by you on your own server. You don't even need jwt_decode. Just use the methods that come with the JWT module you are using to verify the token. In the callback, you will get the payload that was attached to that particular token, use the payload to create a new access token and send that to the frontend.